# Difference between increment of the loop

Tags: javascript

While reading a blog, i came across a condition, which goes into infinite loop, but i didn't understand why, if we try following code

```
for (a=5; a < 10; a+1){
console.log(a);
}
```

this runs as a infinite loop, but with the following it runs fine

```
for (a=5; a < 10; a++){
console.log(a);
}
```

what is the main difference?

Comment: `a + 1` doesn’t change `a`. `a++` changes `a`.

Comment: It should be `a=a+1`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The part

```
for (a = 5; a < 10; a + 1) {
//                  ^^^^^
```

does not change `a`

You need an assignment

```
for (a = 5; a < 10; a = a + 1) {
//                  ^^^
```

If you use `a++` then it resolves to `a = a + 1`

The operator `++` is an [increment operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Increment_()).

Comment: so what does a++ and a+1 means

Comment: @Nofel `a++` -> fetch `a`, return the value, increment the value of `a` by one.`a+1` fetch `a`, add `1` to the result, return the new result (don't change `a`).

Comment: Hmm..., It might worth mentioning a subtle difference here. Even though it's OK for this case, `a = a + 1` is not `a++` in JS while `++a` is.

Comment: @redu, right `a++` is more like `[a, a = a + 1][0]`, like give me `a` and add later one to a.

Comment: in a clearer manner... ++a is the equivalent of doing: a+=1; return a; while a++ is like doing var b = a; a+=1; return b;. In other words, a++ increments a but return it's value PRIOR to the incrementation, while ++a increments a before returning it. if a = 5, if you do console.log(a++);, it'll output 5, and a will now be 6. console.log(++a); would output 6, and a would of course be 6 aswell.

Answer (score 3):

`a++` adds one to `a` **and** stores the result in `a`.¹

`a + 1` just adds one to `a`, *without* storing the result in `a`. (E.g., so you can use the resulting value for something else: `b = a + 1`.)

In the "update" (increment) part of a `for`, you want to modify the loop variable. So you want `a++` (or `++a`), not `a + 1`.

---

¹ Specifically, `a++` (a *postfix increment*) reads the value of `a`, adds one to `a`, and then makes `a`'s previous value the result of the expression. So `a = 1; b = a++;` leaves us with `b == 1` and `a == 2`.

There's also `++a` (a *prefix increment*), which adds one to `a` and *then* uses the resulting value in `a` as the expression's result. So `a = 1; b = ++a;` leaves us with `b == 2` and `a == 2`.

This is sort of indicated visually: In `a++`, the `a` is first, and the increment comes after, and indeed the resulting value of that is of `a` before it was incremented. In `++a`, the increment comes first, then the `a`, which also indicates what we get as a result.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the a+1 part. a+1 simply returns the value of a+1. It doesn't affect anything back to a. a++ actually returns a and then increments it.

Answer (score 0):

The first loop is not incrementing the a variable doing `a+1`, the correct is `a=a+1`:

```
for (a=5; a < 10; a=a+1){
console.log(a);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

a++ means a=a+1
while a+1 doesn't store the value in a
which means a will still 5 forever

Answer (score -1):

it is because it says: 
 a is 0; loop through as long as it is smaller ten; then 1 (becaus 0+1)

you need to add `a++` or `a = a+1`

Answer (score -3):

At the first example you are not increment the value of a
for (a=5; a < 10; a+1 <--- a+1 is not how to add 1 to a value 
You can use a++